# jQuery - Autoselect option on selectbox doesn't function well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have 2 `select` boxes. When I select an option on `selectbox1`, it automatically changes the corresponding value on `selectbox2` regardless of value but order.

The thing is, the code is working fine until after a few tries. Then even if I change the option on `selectbox1`, it doesn't update the one on `selectbox2`.

***To reproduce the issue; go through A to E, then repeat.***

Code:

```js
$(".firstSelectBox").change(function(e) {
  var selectedOption = $("option:selected", this);
  var idx = $(this).children().index(selectedOption)
  var secChildIdx = $(".secondSelectBox").children()[idx];
  $(".secondSelectBox").find(":selected").removeAttr('selected');
  $(secChildIdx).attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <label>First Selectbox</label><br/>
    <select class="firstSelectBox validate[required]">
      <option value="1">Select A</option>
      <option value="2">Select B</option>
      <option value="3">Select C</option>
      <option value="4">Select D</option>
      <option value="5">Select E</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <label>Second Selectbox</label><br />
    <select class="secondSelectBox validate[required]">
      <option value="A">Select 1</option>
      <option value="B">Select 2</option>
      <option value="C">Select 3</option>
      <option value="D">Select 4</option>
      <option value="E">Select 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also JSFiddle version: https://jsfiddle.net/153w074d/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for all that code, just work with [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex):

```js
$(".firstSelectBox").change(function(e) {
  var selectedIndex = $(this).get(0).selectedIndex;
  $(".secondSelectBox").get(0).selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <label>First Selectbox</label><br/>
    <select class="firstSelectBox validate[required]">
      <option value="1">Select A</option>
      <option value="2">Select B</option>
      <option value="3">Select C</option>
      <option value="4">Select D</option>
      <option value="5">Select E</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <label>Second Selectbox</label><br />
    <select class="secondSelectBox validate[required]">
      <option value="A">Select 1</option>
      <option value="B">Select 2</option>
      <option value="C">Select 3</option>
      <option value="D">Select 4</option>
      <option value="E">Select 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

What happened in your original code is that, in some way, the `selected` attributes are being messed around. Try this: Change to each option from A to E, then start over from A, the selection stops working. Then inspect the second `select` to see that there are more than one `option` with `selected="selected"` attribute. Not sure what caused that tho.

Comment: Good answer. FYI the reason for the code not working is OP used `.attr` instead of `.prop`.

Answer (score 1):

@DontVoteMeDown's answer will certainly work, but the reason you're having this issue is because of the discrepancy between `.prop` and `.attr`. Both are similar, but don't refer to the same, identical underlying value.

If you change the below two lines to use the `.prop` value instead of `.attr`, your code will work. See the working code example below.

```
$(".secondSelectBox").find(":selected").removeAttr('selected'); // change to .removeProp
  $(secChildIdx).attr("selected", "selected"); // change to .prop
```

```js
$(".firstSelectBox").change(function(e) {
  var selectedOption = $("option:selected", this);
  var idx = $(this).children().index(selectedOption)
  var secChildIdx = $(".secondSelectBox").children()[idx];
  $(".secondSelectBox").find(":selected").removeProp('selected');
  $(secChildIdx).prop("selected", "selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <label>First Selectbox</label><br/>
    <select class="firstSelectBox validate[required]">
      <option value="1">Select A</option>
      <option value="2">Select B</option>
      <option value="3">Select C</option>
      <option value="4">Select D</option>
      <option value="5">Select E</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <label>Second Selectbox</label><br />
    <select class="secondSelectBox validate[required]">
      <option value="A">Select 1</option>
      <option value="B">Select 2</option>
      <option value="C">Select 3</option>
      <option value="D">Select 4</option>
      <option value="E">Select 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `prop` to select option.

```js
$(".firstSelectBox").change(function(e) {
  var selectedIndex = $(this).get(0).selectedIndex;
  $('.secondSelectBox option:eq('+selectedIndex+')').prop('selected', true); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <label>First Selectbox</label><br/>
    <select class="firstSelectBox validate[required]">
      <option value="1">Select A</option>
      <option value="2">Select B</option>
      <option value="3">Select C</option>
      <option value="4">Select D</option>
      <option value="5">Select E</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <label>Second Selectbox</label><br />
    <select class="secondSelectBox validate[required]">
      <option value="A">Select 1</option>
      <option value="B">Select 2</option>
      <option value="C">Select 3</option>
      <option value="D">Select 4</option>
      <option value="E">Select 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```